# Insert number of days into database according to month

Tags: php, mysql, counter

I've a table `tbl_month` with col `month` and `year` containing values like

```
month    year
  1      2015
  2      2015
  3      2015
  4      2015
  5      2015
............
  12     2015
```

From above table, I'm fetching month and year and want to insert the number of days into table `tbl_days` according to month, so far I be able to insert 30 days with following code:

```
for($count=1;$count<31;$count++) {
    $query="INSERT INTO tbl_days (day_no, brand_id) VALUES ('".$count."','".$_POST['brand_id_'.$count]."')";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

How can I insert number of days according to month into table `tbl_days` e.g for month 12 (December),  31 days and if month 1 (January) again 31 days but for month 2 (Feb) 28 days and if leap year (Feb) 29 days?

Comment: Isn't this pretty pointless if you're not storing the month in `tbl_days` anyway? And as you're not storing the year either, does February have 28 or 29 days?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes for month n year i have another table from which i m fetching month and year. edited and updated the question.

Comment: Were you really stuck for 9 months on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out :

```
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m'), date('Y'));
$query = '';
for($count=1; $count<=$days; $count++) {
   $query .="INSERT INTO tbl_days (day_no, brand_id) VALUES('".$count."', '".$_POST['brand_id_'.$count]."'); \n";
}
// Run query one time instead of "days" time
mysql_query($query);
```